# Sharing data with a service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display the data for every corresponding name(data from json-server) like firstName, lastName, email etc.

**user.component.html** - this is where I want to display the corresponding data

```
<div>
  <h2>{{selectedUser.firstName | uppercase}} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedUser.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>First name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Email:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.email" placeholder="example.com" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Start date:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.startDate" placeholder="Start date" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../user';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users: any

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(data => this.users = data);
  }
}
```

**home.component.html** - this is where I display the name for each user and when I click I want to display the content on the user page

```
<h2>Users</h2>
<ul class="users">
  <a routerLink="/user"><li *ngFor="let user of users['users']"
    [class.selected]="user === selectedUser"
    (click)="onSelect(user)">
    <span class="badge">{{user.id}}</span> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
  </li> </a>
</ul>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../user';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public users = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(data => this.users = data);

  }
}
```

And here is the **data.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from "./user";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  selectedUser: User;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>("http://localhost:3000/users");
  }      

  onSelect(user: User): void {
    console.log(user);
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }
}
```

It's work when I display the names on the home page.
I've also made this display of data on a single page(home.component) and it worked, but now I must to display it on another page. I've tried to do this with BehaviourSubject but I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly accessing the property in your `.html` files. Example:

```
<h2>Users</h2>
<ul class="users">
  <a routerLink="/user"><li *ngFor="let user of users['users']"
    [class.selected]="user === selectedUser"
    (click)="onSelect(user)">
    <span class="badge">{{user.id}}</span> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
  </li> </a>
</ul>
```

Should be:

```
<h2>Users</h2>
<ul class="users">
  <a routerLink="/user"><li *ngFor="let user of users['users']"
    [class.selected]="user === dataService.selectedUser"
    (click)="dataService.onSelect(user)">
    <span class="badge">{{user.id}}</span> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
  </li> </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the `DataService` cache the `users` for you in a `BehaviorSubject` and all components bind to `users$` property of the DataService.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from "./user";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  isLoading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  users$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>(undefined);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadUsers(): void {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);    

    this.http.get<User[]>("http://localhost:3000/users", { observe: "response" }).subscribe(
      (res: HttpResponse<User[]>) => {
        this.users$.next(res.body);
      },
      (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res),
      () => this.isLoading$.next(false)
    );    
  }

  private onError(res: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(res.message);
  }
}
```